# Как создать временную таблицу со структурой постоянной таблицы?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle18c

В *SQL Server* можно создать временную таблицу таким запросом:

```
select * into #mytmptab from mytab;
```

Как добиться того же в *Oracle*?

<sub>По мотивам [топика на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55316087/creation-of-oracle-temporary-table-with-same-table-structure-to-that-of-a-existi).</sub>

Answer (score 8):

В *SQL Server* префикс "#" (hash) в имени таблицы означает - создать временную таблицу, которая видна только в текущей сессии (в противоположность "##" - глобальная временная таблица).

В версии Oracle 18c также появилась возможность создать приватные временные таблицы, которые по завершению сессии (по-умолчанию транзакции без предиката `on commit`) будут полностью разрушены. Префикс обязателен и определён параметром `private_temp_table_prefix` (по-умолчанию `ORA$PTT_`). Например:

```
create table mytab as 
    select 1 id, cast ('aaa' as varchar2 (32)) name from dual
;

show parameter private

NAME                      TYPE   VALUE    
------------------------- ------ -------- 
private_temp_table_prefix string ORA$PTT_ 

create private temporary table ora$ptt_mytab on commit preserve definition as
    select * from mytab where 1=0
;
Private TEMPORARY created.
```

И используем как обычные таблицы:

```
declare
    r mytab%rowtype;
begin 
    insert into ora$ptt_mytab values (2, 'bbb');
    select id + 1, name||'x' into r from ora$ptt_mytab where rownum = 1;
    insert into ora$ptt_mytab values r;
end;
/
select * from mytab 
union all
select * from ora$ptt_mytab;

        ID NAME                            
---------- --------------------------------
         1 aaa                             
         2 bbb                             
         3 bbbx
```

С некоторыми ограничениями:

- для `%rowtype` они не доступны
- в именных PL/SQL блоках они могут использоваться только в динамическом SQL, т.к. во время компиляции их ещё нет

В офф. док. [Creating Private Temporary Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/admin/managing-tables.html#GUID-9B373086-0760-4B18-9688-BACFF07EC74B).

Comment: восхитительно, не знал, что так можно в новых версиях)

Comment: похоже пора таки ознакомиться с `18c New Features` :)